# Custom Aggregation/Column Concatenation Within an MDX Query

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a `date` dimension and a `time` dimension and a measure called `[Count - Sales]`. I would like to run a query that would give me the count of sales over a range of `time` on a given date, and also concatenate the `date` and `time` values and show me the start and end `date-time`. So the end results I am expecting would look something like this:

```
StartDateTime | EndDateTime | Count - Sales
------------------------------------------------
20130901 12   | 20130901 16 | 4000
20130902 12   | 20130902 16 | 4123
```

I have come up with a way to concatenate the date and time values, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to have the two columns `StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime`. The query I have right now gives me the `[Count - Sales]` for every hour:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.DateTime AS 
       [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Name + " " + [Time].[Hour 24].CurrentMember.Name + ":00"
SELECT 
{{[Date].[Date].&[20131101]:[Date].[Date].&[20131101]}*{[Time].[Hour 24].&[10]:[Time].[Hour 24].&[14]},
{[Date].[Date].&[20131102]:[Date].[Date].&[20131102]}*{[Time].[Hour 24].&[10]:[Time].[Hour 24].&[14]} } ON ROWS,

  {Measures.DateTime, 
  [Measures].[Count - Sales] } ON COLUMNS
  FROM Sales
```

And the result is:

```
Date        Time    DateTime      Count - Sales
20131101    10     20131101 10    206
20131101    11     20131101 11    251
20131101    12     20131101 12    318
20131101    13     20131101 13    304
20131101    14     20131101 14    300
20131102    10     20131102 10    194
20131102    11     20131102 11    251
20131102    12     20131102 12    298
20131102    13     20131102 13    329
20131102    14     20131102 14    345
```

Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH SET [Time Range Set] AS
         [Time].[Hour 24].&[10] : [Time].[Hour 24].&[14]
     MEMBER [Time].[Hour 24].TimeRange AS
            Aggregate([Time Range Set])
     MEMBER Measures.StartDateTime AS 
            [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Name + " "
            + [Time Range Set].Item(0).Item(0).Name + ":00"
     MEMBER Measures.EndDateTime AS 
            [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Name + " "
            + Tail([Time Range Set]).Item(0).Item(0).Name + ":59"
SELECT 
     { Measures.StartDateTime, Measures.EndDateTime, [Measures].[Count - Sales] }
     ON COLUMNS,
     {[Date].[Date].&[20131101]:[Date].[Date].&[20131102]}
     *
     {[Time].[Hour 24].TimeRange}
     ON ROWS
FROM Sales
```

On the rows, you only want to show two days, and the time range member for each one. The `.Item(0).Item(0)` construct gets the first member of the first tuple of a set. Hence, we can use it directly for the `StartDateTime`, but need to apply `Tail`, which returns a set containing the last tuple of the set to which it is applied.

Please note that specifying ROWS before COLUMNS violates the MDX specification (but Analysis Services is tolerant and interprets it correctly).